# ActiveReports Server - custom data model

Tags: c#, activereports

Using ActiveReports Server, the designer will facilitate the creation of reports from the start. In the data binding part you can select data source as Standard SQL server etc..but what if I want to pull that metadata on table definitions and table schema over a JSON api, is there a way to do that?

If that is not possible can I define my own data models on the runtime and then bind it report to the JSON web-service?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveReports Server data models currently support relational databases. So the data that the server queries through the data models needs to be in database.

For getting data from a web-service, you could try to first put the data through into a database and then report off of that.

With that said, could you elaborate on your need for report creation? Are you using the web based report designer add-on for your report creation? There are options that you could evaluate with runtime datasets with ActiveReports developer reports running on the ActiveReports Server.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. An ETL route will be hard to do for us as we are pursuing a ad-hoc approach and our database is XML based. We have JSON api tp get data and metadata (schema). Hence we are trying the see if a direct connection can be made. 

Yes, I am considering the web-based report designer and server component. Let us know if there is anything on your roadmap for such a need.